# Email not getting sent php jq modal form

Tags: php, jquery, email

Can someone here help me out, i created this modal form which somehow isn't sending success mail sent response, i instead end up getting the "Some problem occurred, please try again." response after submitting the form.

I just cannot seem to understand what is wrong in here?

my html code

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modalbg">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Fill out.</h4>                
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="requestinfo" method="post">
                <h3>START PLANNING</h3>
                <p style="color:#0066FF;">YOUR CONTACT DETAILS</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Full Name</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label><br/>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputMobile">Mobile</label><br/>
                        <input type="mobile" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputState">Select State</label><br/>
                        <select name="state" class="form-control" id="inputState" >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="California">California</option>
                            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="District Of Columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
                            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="New York">New York</option>

                            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                            <option value="Not Listed">Not Listed</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>
                <p style="color:#0066FF;"><b>TELL US ABOUT YOUR PLANS</b></p>
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPlans">Plan Status</label><br/>
                        <select name="plans" class="form-control" id="inputPlans" >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Bags packed, I'm ready to go!">Bags packed, I'm ready to go!</option>
                            <option value="Still in planning mode">Still in planning mode</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputDestination">Destination</label><br/>
                        <select name="destionation" class="form-control" id="inputDestination" >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
                            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                            <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
                            <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
                            <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                            <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>  
                    <br/>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputTravellers">Total Travelers</label><br/>
                        <select name="travelers" class="form-control" id="inputTravelers" >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
                            <option value="2 people">2 people</option>
                            <option value="3 people">3 people</option>
                            <option value="4 people">4 people</option>
                            <option value="5 people">5 people</option>
                            <option value="6 people">6 people</option>
                            <option value="7 people">7 people</option>
                            <option value="8 people">8 people</option>
                            <option value="9 people">9 people</option>
                            <option value="10 people">10 people</option>
                            <option value="10+ people">10+ people</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>  
                    <br/>   
              <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputTravelWithin">Travelling Within</label><br/>
                        <select name="travelwithin" class="form-control" id="inputTravelWithin" >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="0-1 months">0-1 months</option>
                            <option value="1-3 months">1-3 months</option>
                            <option value="3-6 months">3-6 months</option>
                            <option value="6-9 months">6-9 months</option>
                            <option value="6-9 months">6-9 months</option>
                            <option value="9-12 months">9-12 months</option>
                            <option value="12+ months">12+ months</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>              
                <br/>       
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputComments">Comments</label><br/>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputComments" cols="60" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                     
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function submitContactForm(){
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var mobile = $('#inputMobile').val();
    var state = $('#inputState').val();
    var plans = $('#inputPlans').val();
    var destination = $('#inputDestination').val();
    var travelers = $('#inputTravelers').val();
    var travelwithin = $('#inputTravelWithin').val();
    var message = $('#inputComments').val();
    if(name.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;   
    }else if(mobile.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your mobile.');
        $('#inputMobile').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(state.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please select your state.');
        $('#inputState').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(plans.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please select your plan.');
        $('#inputPlans').focus();
        return false;   
    }else if(destination.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please select destination.');
        $('#inputDestination').focus();
        return false;   
    }else if(travelers.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please select total travellers.');
        $('#inputTravelers').focus();
        return false;                   
    }else if(travelwithin.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please select travelling within.');
        $('#inputTravelWithin').focus();
        return false;       
    }else if(message.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your comments.');
        $('#inputComments').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'requestform.php',
            data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&mobile='+mobile+'&state='+state+'&plans='+plans+'&destination='+destination+'&travelers='+travelers+'&travelwithin='+travelwithin+'&message='+message,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#inputName').val('');
                    $('#inputEmail').val('');
                    $('#inputMobile').val('');
                    $('#inputState').val('');
                    $('#inputPlans').val('');
                    $('#inputDestination').val('');
                    $('#inputTravelers').val('');
                    ('#inputTravelWithin').val('');
                    $('#inputComments').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</p>');
                    $('#requestinfo').trigger("reset");
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    $('#requestinfo').trigger("reset");
                }
                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

and here is my requestform.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['contactFrmSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) && !empty($_POST['mobile']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['plans']) && !empty($_POST['destionation']) && !empty($_POST['travelers']) && !empty($_POST['travelwithin']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
        
        // Submitted form data
        $name   = $_POST['name'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile  = $_POST['mobile'];
        $state  = $_POST['state'];
        $plans  = $_POST['plans'];
        $destionation  = $_POST['destionation'];
        $travelers  = $_POST['travelers'];
        $travelwithin  = $_POST['travelwithin'];
        $message= $_POST['message'];
        
        /*
         * Send email to admin
         */
        $to     = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $subject= 'New Request Info';
        
         $htmlContent = '
        <h4>Contact request has submitted at CodexWorld, details are given below.</h4>
        <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Mobile:</th><td>'.$mobile.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>State:</th><td>'.$state.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Plans:</th><td>'.$plans.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Destination:</th><td>'.$destionation.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Total Travellers:</th><td>'.$travelers.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                <th>Travel Within:</th><td>'.$travelwithin.'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;padding:10px;">Comments</p>
        <p'.$message.'p>';
        
        // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        
        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'From: CodexWorld<sender@example.com>' . "\r\n";
        
        // Send email
       if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
        $status = 'ok';
    }else{
        $status = 'err';
    }
    
    // Output status
    echo $status;die;
}
    
    ?>
```

will really appreciate if someone here could help me sort this.

Comment: Have you first of all checked what response the request actually got, in the network panel of your browser dev tools?

Comment: I do not seem to be getting any response thats the case

Comment: That does not make sense; then your jQuery ajax code would have no reason to go into the success branch to begin with, but that is where the message you are seeing is coming from.

Comment: Don't confuse an _empty_ response (empty as in, no data in the response body), with "no response at all."

Comment: Are you running this on your localhost machine? or live server?

Comment: Status
200
OK
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred992 B (0 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes but i also tried it on webhost still same issue

Comment: Your PHP script won't output much, if the initial if-conditions are not fulfilled. Have you checked yet, whether they actually are? A quick way to do that would be to take everything between the (...), and put that into a `var_dump` at the very beginning of the script, that should get you either true or false in the response.

Comment: did that no nothing in  error_logs